Traefik https setting with AWS acm returns 404 not found error
I'm using traefik as a Reverse Proxy for my web service in AWS EKS environment.
ingressClass:
    enabled: true
    isDefaultClass: true
    fallbackApiVersion: v1
ingressRoute:
    dashboard:
    enabled: true
providers:
    kubernetesCRD:
    allowCrossNamespace: true
nodeSelector:
    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup: [node-group]
service:
    annotation:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: internal
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: [arn]

=> traefik/values.yaml

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
    name: ingress-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: PathPrefix(`{{ .Values.env.normal.BACKEND_ROOT_PATH }}`)
      services:
      - name: backend
        port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: PathPrefix(`{{ .Values.env.normal.FRONTEND_ROOT_PATH }}`)
      services: 
      - name: frontend
        port: 80

=> app/ingress-route.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aicert-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: {{ .Values.env.normal.BACKEND_ROOT_PATH }}
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend
            port:
              number: 80
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: {{ .Values.env.normal.FRONTEND_ROOT_PATH }}
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80

=> app/ingress.yaml

If I install with helm command,then I can connect with 80 port with my domain setting. But with 443 port, I cannot connect (404 page not found error occurs)
Is there any additional settings (for ingress) that shoud I set additional setting to connect 443(https) connect? or is there an incorrect setting with above codes?
